# Ext.data.model doesnt parse data from object

Tags: javascript, extjs, model

I have ExtJs model

```
Ext.define('ManageProducts.model.Related', {
    extend            : 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields    : [
        {
            mapping: 'sequence',
            name   : 'sequence',
            type   : 'int',
            defaultValue: null
        },
        {
            mapping: 'relatedProduct.id',
            name   : 'relatedProduct.id',
            type   : 'int'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'relatedProduct.name',
            name   : 'relatedProduct.name',
            type   : 'string'
        },
        {
            mapping: 'relatedProduct.sku',
            name   : 'relatedProduct.sku',
            type   : 'string'
        },
        {
            name        : 'relatedProduct.pricing.price',
            type        : 'float',
            defaultValue: null
        },
        {
            name        : 'relatedProduct.pricing.id',
            type        : 'int',
            defaultValue: null
        },
        {
            mapping: 'relatedProduct.status.id',
            name   : 'relatedProduct.status.id',
            type   : 'int'
        },
        {
            name        : 'relatedProduct.categories',
            type        : 'auto',
            defaultValue: []
        }
    ],
    idProperty: 'relatedProduct.id'
});
```

And code which has to create model from data

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
model = Ext.ModelManager.create(data[i], 'ManageProducts.model.Related');
}
```

So model data looks like

```
accessoryProduct.categories: Array[0]
accessoryProduct.id: 0
accessoryProduct.name: ""
accessoryProduct.pricing.id: 0
accessoryProduct.pricing.price: 0
accessoryProduct.sku: ""
sequence: 2
status.id: 0
```

so its empty, except sequence which is in root of data

and data[i] is

```
sequence: 2
relatedProduct: Object {
categories: Array[1]
deletedAt: null
description: "Adult Male Asian Articulated Skeleton Description"
educational: "educational for Test product."
id: 6
isGroup: false
name: "Adult Male Asian Articulated Skeleton"
pricing: Object
quantity: 8
sequence: null
showEducational: false
showGroupProducts: false
sku: "SC-092-A"
status: Object
}
__proto__: Object
```

So the question is why created model is empty?
As I know it correctly parses data from server...
But why it is not in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use ModelManager to create the instance(s). Use standard Ext.create:

```
var model = Ext.create('ManageProducts.model.Related', data[i]);
```

Another correct way is:

```
var model = ManageProducts.model.Related.create(data[i])
```

First way is preferred as if model class is not loaded Ext makes an attempt to load it before creation but if you use the second way and model class is not loaded it just fails.